# Strange characters from char array in structure

Tags: c, arrays, char, structure

Here are my structures (defined in a header file):

```
typedef struct                          
{
    char            *name;
    char            *value;
} struct_param;

typedef struct                          
{
  char              *UID;               
  int               number;             
  char              *type;              
  char              *name;              
  struct_param      param[10];          
} struct_cmd;
```

the prototype :

`struct_cmd *ParseFile(char buffer[]);`

The function in the c file:

```
struct_cmd *ParseFile(char buffer[])
{
struct_cmd      *cmd;
cmd = malloc(sizeof(struct_cmd));
...
if (mxmlGetFirstChild(node_msgUID) != NULL)
    cmd->UID = node_msgUID->child->value.opaque;

...
printf("Message Type :: %s | Message UID :: %s \n", cmd->type, cmd->UID);
...

return cmd;
```

}

The printf in ParseFile works perfectly.

Now, from the main function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ...
    struct_cmd *mystruct;
    mystruct = malloc(sizeof(struct_cmd));
    mystruct = ParseFile(buf);
    printf("Message Type :: %s | Message UID :: %s \n", mystruct->type, mystruct->UID);
    ...
}
```

The same printf doesn't work. The function returns the structure, but values are weird... It's not values, but strange characters.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: you must have done `cmd = malloc(sizeof(struct_cmd))` or `cmd = &var` , where is this done, you are probabbly reading intoa varible that is out of scope

Comment: This makes no sense: `struct_cmd = *cmd;`. You are assigning value to type. Compiler should at least warn about this. Are you not showing all the code?

Comment: No change. I've added it in the function which fill and return the structure and before the call of this function. In the function, the printf still works, but not in the main project.

Comment: It's just an error of typing. The declaration is : struct_cmd *cmd; And no, I'm not showing all the code. Do you need more?

Comment: Edit the question and post all *relevant* code.

Comment: Done. Hope it's clearer.

Comment: while we can *guess* what the problem is, we *expect* code, which *reproduces* the problem. post a compilable example.

Comment: the `type` and `UID` are pointers. you do not provide the code where they are being allocated/set and this is where the problem most likely lies. `cmd->UID = node_msgUID->child->value.opaque;` note that if the value of `node_msgUID->child->value.opaque` changes, so will your `UID`

Comment: also: you are allocating `sizeof(struct_cmd)` then overwriting the value with the call to `ParseFile` , you have a memory leak right there

Comment: What do you mean by "you do not provide the code where they are being allocated/set". This line cmd->UID = node_msgUID->child->value.opaque; doesn't do it?

Comment: And yes, I moved the malloc after the function call, but there's no change.

Comment: You are doing malloc twice on the same variable, once inside `ParseFile` and once in `main`, that's a problem, but not your current problem. `cmd->UID = node_msgUID->child->value.opaque` sets the pointer `UID` to the pointer `opaque`. If `opaque` changes so does `UID`

Comment: OK, so I removed the second malloc (in the main). Opaque is set after the xml file parsing. It's not supposed to change alone. I tried something else. Just before leaving ParseFile function, I do this :
cmd->type = "type";
In this case, the cmd_>type in the main shows "type".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a *shallow* copy from the data allocated by [Mini-XML](http://www.msweet.org/projects.php?Z3) to your own struct `cmd`.

For example, this statement copies a *pointer*, not the actual characters:

```
cmd->UID = node_msgUID->child->value.opaque;
```

`cmd->UID` still refers to the original memory block allocated by Mini-XML. There's nothing wrong with that, just remember that this memory will be de-allocated once you call [mxmlDelete](http://www.msweet.org/documentation/project3/Mini-XML.html#mxmlDelete). Which is probably what you are doing somewhere near the end of function `ParseFile`. I am guessing here, since you did not post all your code.

Possible solutions:

1. Instead of a *shallow* copy, make a *deep* copy, e.g. with *strdup*: `cmd->UID = strdup(node_msgUID->child->value.opaque);`
2. Do all processing *before* freeing memory.

Remember, you are programming in plain C, without a garbage collector. Memory management is your responsibility.

Comment: Many thanks Sir! You're right, I'm calling mxmlDelete at the end of ParseFile function. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure... I must use malloc before setting the value to my structure in the ParseFile function, right?

So as I said in a comment, if I manually set cmd->type = "type" in the ParseFile function, it's correctly showed in the console (in the main).

But if I don't, strange characters are displayed.

I changed the declaration of my structure and added "extern", but it didn't change anything.

I'm lost...

Answer (score -1):

define cmd globally instead of locally in the function:

```
struct_cmd *ParseFile(char buffer[])
{
struct_cmd      *cmd;
cmd = malloc(sizeof(struct_cmd));
...
if (mxmlGetFirstChild(node_msgUID) != NULL)
    cmd->UID = node_msgUID->child->value.opaque;

...
printf("Message Type :: %s | Message UID :: %s \n", cmd->type, cmd->UID);
...

return cmd;
}
```

to:

```
struct_cmd      *cmd;
struct_cmd *ParseFile(char buffer[])
{
cmd = malloc(sizeof(struct_cmd));
...
if (mxmlGetFirstChild(node_msgUID) != NULL)
    cmd->UID = node_msgUID->child->value.opaque;

...
printf("Message Type :: %s | Message UID :: %s \n", cmd->type, cmd->UID);
...

return cmd;
}
```

Comment: Your advice makes sense for non-scalar types. For a pointer like `cmd`, it has no effect. Except that you're making `cmd`'s scope global, which is bad practice.